BrokenPipeError when fetching from API for Matrix Portal M4
I'm working on a project using an ESP32 with CircuitPython, specifically the Adafruit Matrix Portal M4. I'm trying to fetch data from the an API (https://api.wheresthefuckingtrain.com/by-id/A31), but I'm encountering a BrokenPipeError when I attempt to retrieve the data.
Retrieving data...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 81, in <module>
  File "code.py", line 25, in get_arrival_times
  File "adafruit_portalbase/network.py", line 645, in fetch_data
  File "adafruit_portalbase/network.py", line 563, in fetch
  File "adafruit_requests.py", line 715, in get
  File "adafruit_requests.py", line 647, in request
  File "adafruit_connection_manager.py", line 347, in get_socket
  File "adafruit_connection_manager.py", line 249, in _get_connected_socket
  File "adafruit_connection_manager.py", line 61, in connect
  File "adafruit_esp32spi/adafruit_esp32spi_socketpool.py", line 114, in connect
  File "adafruit_esp32spi/adafruit_esp32spi.py", line 917, in socket_connect
  File "adafruit_esp32spi/adafruit_esp32spi.py", line 813, in socket_open
  File "adafruit_esp32spi/adafruit_esp32spi.py", line 430, in _send_command_get_response
  File "adafruit_esp32spi/adafruit_esp32spi.py", line 400, in _wait_response_cmd
  File "adafruit_esp32spi/adafruit_esp32spi.py", line 382, in _check_data
BrokenPipeError: Expected 01 but got 00

Here is what my code looks like, following the source code from this creator:
import time
import microcontroller
from board import NEOPIXEL
import displayio
import adafruit_display_text.label
from adafruit_datetime import datetime
from adafruit_bitmap_font import bitmap_font
from adafruit_matrixportal.matrix import Matrix
from adafruit_matrixportal.network import Network

STOP_ID = 'A31'
DATA_SOURCE = 'https://api.wheresthefuckingtrain.com/by-id/%s' % (STOP_ID,)
DATA_LOCATION = ["data"]
UPDATE_DELAY = 15
SYNC_TIME_DELAY = 30
MINIMUM_MINUTES_DISPLAY = 9
BACKGROUND_IMAGE = 'assets/g-dashboard.bmp'
ERROR_RESET_THRESHOLD = 3

def get_arrival_in_minutes_from_now(now, date_str):
    train_date = datetime.fromisoformat(date_str).replace(tzinfo=None) # Remove tzinfo to be able to diff dates
    return round((train_date-now).total_seconds()/60.0)

def get_arrival_times():
    stop_trains =  network.fetch_data(DATA_SOURCE, json_path=(DATA_LOCATION,))
    stop_data = stop_trains[0]
    nortbound_trains = [x['time'] for x in stop_data['N']]
    southbound_trains = [x['time'] for x in stop_data['S']]

    now = datetime.now()
    print("Now: ", now)

    nortbound_arrivals = [get_arrival_in_minutes_from_now(now, x) for x in nortbound_trains]
    southound_arrivals = [get_arrival_in_minutes_from_now(now, x) for x in southbound_trains]

    n = [str(x) for x in nortbound_arrivals if x>= MINIMUM_MINUTES_DISPLAY]
    s = [str(x) for x in southound_arrivals if x>= MINIMUM_MINUTES_DISPLAY]

    n0 = n[0] if len(n) > 0 else '-'
    n1 = n[1] if len(n) > 1 else '-'
    s0 = s[0] if len(s) > 0 else '-'
    s1 = s[1] if len(s) > 1 else '-'

    return n0,n1,s0,s1

def update_text(n0, n1, s0, s1):
    text_lines[2].text = "%s,%s m" % (n0,n1)
    text_lines[4].text = "%s,%s m" % (s0,s1)
    display.root_group = group

# --- Display setup ---
matrix = Matrix()
display = matrix.display
network = Network(status_neopixel=NEOPIXEL, debug=False)

# --- Drawing setup ---
group = displayio.Group()
bitmap = displayio.OnDiskBitmap(open(BACKGROUND_IMAGE, 'rb'))
colors = [0x444444, 0xDD8000]  # [dim white, gold]

font = bitmap_font.load_font("assets/fonts/6x10.bdf")
text_lines = [
    displayio.TileGrid(bitmap, pixel_shader=getattr(bitmap, 'pixel_shader', displayio.ColorConverter())),
    adafruit_display_text.label.Label(font, color=colors[0], x=20, y=3, text="Queens"),
    adafruit_display_text.label.Label(font, color=colors[1], x=20, y=11, text="- mins"),
    adafruit_display_text.label.Label(font, color=colors[0], x=20, y=20, text="Church"),
    adafruit_display_text.label.Label(font, color=colors[1], x=20, y=28, text="- mins"),
]
for x in text_lines:
    group.append(x)
display.root_group = group

error_counter = 0
last_time_sync = None
while True:
    try:
        if last_time_sync is None or time.monotonic() > last_time_sync + SYNC_TIME_DELAY:
            # Sync clock to minimize time drift
            network.get_local_time()
            last_time_sync = time.monotonic()
        arrivals = get_arrival_times()
        update_text(*arrivals)
    except (ValueError, RuntimeError) as e:
        print("Some error occured, retrying! -", e)
        error_counter = error_counter + 1
        if error_counter > ERROR_RESET_THRESHOLD:
            microcontroller.reset()

    time.sleep(UPDATE_DELAY)

I've seen elsewhere online that I might need to upgrade the Nina firmware. When doing so, I get stuck on the "Upload NINA Firmware" step, and the Adafruit ESPTool has the error:
Connecting...
Connected successfully.
Try hard reset.
[Object.debug:191] Finished read loop
Error: Couldn't sync to ESP. Try resetting.

I keep resetting to no avail. Can someone please help?
